# Custom Windows Login

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-authentication, biometrics

Is it possible to customize windows OS login with c# , like Lenovo veriface. I want to override the default to login in windows 8

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VeriFace

What all libraries are available and any examples , also how to show a custom form on login screen / lock screen .

Comment: I will be checking this.. thanks